# Can I get 10 Gig on cat6a running through two wall jacks?

Tags: ethernet

I'd like to have cat6a running from the basement to a second floor room. I'd like to have a wall jack installed in the addict and plug a cable into that jack that runs into the second floor room. I want this kind of setup so I can add a switch in the future for more upstairs drops. Will going through two outlets cause any performance issues?

Comment: Um do you mean 10m? Cat 6 is only rated to megabit. Leaving as a comment as I haven’t done any backbones lately but have used fiber when those kind of speeds were required.

Answer (score 2):

If everything is done properly, this will work fine. However, every component - in-wall cable, jacks, patch cables, network cards - has to be able to support 10 Gig. **Plus, your installation quality (especially installation of the jacks) needs to be perfect.**

Comment: Cat6 is good for max 55m on 10GBASE-T. Check your lengths, as well as everything else.

Comment: @tetsujin , your comment got me looking further it looks like cat 6a is a lot like 5E a half way step where if not absolutely perfect it did not make the speeds.+

Comment: @EdBeal - Oops! Sorry, I'd missed the 'a', my bad. I wired my entire house in 5E 20+ years ago, when it was considered 'future-proof'… I don't want to have to rip it out any time soon ;) I do have one line that keeps flipping back to 100BASE-T & I'm avoiding having to dig it out.

Answer (score 0):

Um do you mean 10MB?
Cat 6 is only rated to megabit.
I haven’t done any backbones lately but have used fiber when those kind of speeds were required.
After leaving the comment I checked.

cat 7 10GB

cat 8 40GB,

cat 6 1000MB or 1 GB is the certified speed.

Yet another update I found cat 6a
The transfer rate can be up to 10GB but the bandwidth is 500mhz .
I have not worked with it but I would believe unless you have everything perfect you will not make the max speed. This looks similar to cat 5 and 5E if things were not absolutely perfect 5E was not much better than 5.

The rest of the answer removed as it was cat 6 specific.

Answer (score -2):

If you want a high chance of success in getting 10Gb speeds through wall jacks you ought to hire an experienced professional, contract that person to achieve the result you want and not concern yourself with what kind of cable they use inside the walls.  Let them decide.

If you want to do this yourself using wire and jacks you buy online, and you don't have extensive experience, it's unlikely you'll achieve reliable 10Gb speeds.  You'll probably have to build your own wall jacks.  I'm not sure but I don't think you can buy fully assembled domestic ethernet walljacks that are Cat6a or 10G compatible.

Your options:

1. Ask yourself why you need such high wire speeds, particularly why you need it at a wall jack on the second floor.  If you have a good reason, you can probably justify the cost of having a professional do it.
2. If you really need the speed and really can't afford a pro, your best bet is to skip the jacks, buy a high quality prefabricated patch cord that is long enough to reach point to point between your locations, and carefully (without kinking or damaging it) run that through your house.  Use that as a backbone with a 10G switch at each end.   That will dramatically increase your chance of success.

Comment: Two downvotes with no explanations?  I presume this is because recommending a professional is not appreciated in this DIY forum?  If so I suppose the downvotes are fair.  I would appreciate the explanation however.   And despite that, I stand by my answer.  If you want reliable 10Gb connectivity AND you want it through domestic wall jacks AND you have no experience with this .... it is not a DIY project!

Comment: I'm one of the down voters. For one thing, I never like the "big patch cord" suggestion - as hard as it is to make a good punch to a jack, making a good crimp of a plug is harder, which means when the plug inevitably breaks you need to buy - and pull through two floors again - a new patch cable.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact fair enough, that was meant as a compromise and certainly has its faults.  But what I want to know is why OP needs 10Gb ethernet at home, and why the devices communicating at such speed need to be spread all around the house?   There's just something that doesn't add up about this question.

Comment: I actually agree with you on that. I've seen people head for Gigabit when they only have a 50 Megabit internet connection and the only thing shared is a printer. On the other hand, I occasionally need to transfer stuff between computers, so I put in Gigabit (but not 10 Gigabit...) even though for internet usage 100 Meg. is plenty. OP may have a good reason - or they may just be hooked on "latest & greatest". No idea...

Comment: Well to be fair you could have several devices upstairs and a server in the basement with combined comms rates of, maybe not 10Gb, but more than 1Gb and you could use a 10Gb wired backhaul for the upstairs WAP or mesh node.  I still don't see how wall jacks make this a better picture (unless OP shares your distaste for running patch cords between floors).